# Custom CSS Grid Border Using Image

Tags: html, css, next.js, css-grid

I'm working on a project for a client using nextjs, and the design requires me to have a component with a custom border on a responsive CSS grid. I've made the CSS grid with all the content inside, however I'm having a lot of trouble adding the border that the design calls for.

So far I've tried making the border part of the background, but that gets screwy when I move between devices, I've also tried using an `aftter` pseudo element but I didn't get anywhere with that.

I need the border on the CSS grid to look like the image below:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want rectangle boxes on corner ?? Right?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and show us what you have tried.

Comment: @Developer yes that's what I want.

Comment: @jerome I have put two possible solutions in answer. Try that

Comment: @jerome this question really good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it more quickly using [border-image property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image). Take a **square image shape** and put in the border of the div. The attached linked above has a relatable example of it. Have a look at it.

**OR**

You can try this which doesn't require image:-

```css
.container{
   display: flex;
}

.container > .box{
   padding: 2rem 1rem;
   border: 1px solid black;
   position: relative;
}

.container > .box:nth-child(odd):before,
.container > .box:after
{
   content: '';
   display: block;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: pink;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
}

.container > .box:before{
   top: -5px;
   left: -5px;
}

.container > .box:after{
   top: -5px;
   right: -5px;
}

.container > .box:nth-child(odd) > span:before,
.container > .box > span:after
{
content: '';
   display: block;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: pink;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
}

.container > .box > span:before{
   bottom: -5px;
   left: -5px;
}

.container > .box > span:after{
   bottom: -5px;
   right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
     <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
     <span>Ipsum Lorem</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried using the border image property earlier, what happened was the squares at each junction overlapped, and when I was shrinking the screen, they separated.

The second method solved this issue! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jerome my pleasure. Mark right answer correct for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

If transparency is not needed you can try to use gradients combined with `border-image`

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  height: 300px;
  margin: 30px;
  /* simulate the border using a grid made with conic-gradient*/
  background: 
   conic-gradient(from 90deg at 1px 1px,#0000 25%,#7a97fb 0)
   0 0/calc((100% - 1px)/3) calc((100% - 1px)/2)
}
.box div {
  position: relative;
}
.box div:before,
.box div:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* create 4 squares on the corners with 14px size */
  border-image: 
   linear-gradient(#7a97fb 0 0) 50%/
    14px/7px; /* width / (width/2) */
}
.box div:after {
  /* create 4 squares on the corners above the previous ones with 12px size
     leaving 1px on each side for the border you need 
  */
  border-image: 
   /* the color here must match the background color */
   linear-gradient(#ebf0f3 0 0) 50%/
    12px/6px; 
}



body {
 background: #ebf0f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both of these answers work, just what I needed :)